# How to add a FAB using stack when floatingActionButtonLocation is defined?

Tags: flutter

In my application I have defined a FAB with the property `floatingActionButtonLocation` set to `FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked`. I have defined a bottom app bar that holds the centerDocked FAB. I also want to use a `Stack` widget to position two additional FABs on the top right of the screen. It should look something similar to this - [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ovQY.png)

But when I tried to use a `Stack`, the FAB which is present in the bottom app bar is displayed but the two FABs under the stack widget are invisible.

[docked FAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehobf.jpg)

[FABs under stack widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zB4v.jpg)

code where I have defined the `Stack`

```
 return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
         Positioned(

           // the below values for stack are experimental at the moment

           left: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.width * 0.60,
           right: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.width * 0.01,
//           top: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.20,
//           bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.7,
           child: Row(
             children: <Widget>[

               // invisible FABs

               FloatingActionButton(
                 onPressed: (){
                   _animate2Pagenegative();
//              print(widget.date);
                 },
                 child: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                 heroTag: UniqueKey(),
               ),
               FloatingActionButton(
                 onPressed: (){
                   _animate2Pageforward();
//              print(widget.date);
                 },
                 heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                 child: Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),

            // FAB which is displayed correctly
            FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () async{
                String result1 =   await Navigator.push( // string which stores the user entered value
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => InputScreen(), //screen which has TextField
                    ));
                setState(() {
                  addItem(result1, false, "");
                });
              },
              tooltip: 'Add a task',
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
)
```

body of Scaffold:

```
  body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new DaysPageView(
//                onDaysChanged: getDatestring,
                physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                dayoverride: getDate(widget.date),
                scrollDirection: _scrollDirection,
                pageSnapping: _pageSnapping,
                reverse: _reverse,
                controller: _daysPageController,
                pageBuilder: _daysPageBuilder,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Comment: understood, I had accidentally clicked post question. I have updated my question now.

Comment: apologies for that.

Comment: Would you please elaborate about the two other FloatingActionsButtons? Do you mean the left/right arrows?

Comment: correct, I am having difficulty in placing the FABs on that exact position.

Comment: Why do you need them to be FABs?

Comment: due to my application's specification...

Comment: OK, let me explain a bit. Are you thinking of it as a FAB because you need them to be always visible? I mean why did you though of multiple FABs?

Comment: yes, So the FAB which is under ```centerDocked``` is supposed to execute one specific task and the other two FABs are supposed to execute two different tasks. All the FABs need to be visible. I tried to use a ```Stack``` widget since it looked like the closest thing that could solve my issue. But when i used it, the non CenterDocked FABs are invisible. I used the flutter inspector to check where exactly the two FABs were getting rendered.

Comment: Is my answer clear?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need other FloatingActionsButtons to do that design. What I understand is that you need the upper part not to scroll with the content hence you thought of FABs. There are multiple ways to achieve that. Here is an example, I'm using colors to show you the different parts of your screen. And of course these are random sizes to show the case.

```
return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                child: Text(
                  "- 2 TASKS MORE",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('left arrow pressed');
                },
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_left)
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('right arrow pressed');
                },
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 600,
                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[

          ],
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        onPressed: ()
        async {
          print('FAB pressed');
        },
        tooltip: 'Add a task',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
    );
```

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: Hey Osama! Unfortunately i cannot use this exact solution since the ```body:``` of my scaffold is occupied by another widget which needs to be extended to the entire screen. Hence i need to utilize the ```floatingActionButton``` property of my scaffold in order to achieve the desired design.

Comment: The entire screen that you see in the image that i have provided is occupied by this widget. I have defined a ```bottomNavigationBar``` property for my Scaffold, which is why the screen was able to display this widget.

Comment: I have added the code which displays the ```body``` of my scaffold.

Comment: I undertand that you have another ```body``` and ```bottomNavigationBar```. My code is just a demonstration. You should replace ```SingleChildScrollView``` in my code with your body content (starting from Expanded part). You see you can think of the body as everything above the ```bottomNavigationBar```.